# Como alterar 2 ou mais colunas ao mesmo tempo no Sql Server 2014? (ALTER TABLE/ALTER COLUMN)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço para alterar 3 colunas ao mesmo tempo na tabela do SQL SERVER?

Quero alterar o `COLLATION`, mas poderia ser outra coisa.

Tentei:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL,
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS_OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
NULL,
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS_ENDERECO VARCHAR(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
NULL
```

Tentei também:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL,
COLUMN VIS_DS_OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
COLUMN VIS_DS_ENDERECO VARCHAR(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL
```

E também:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL,
VIS_DS_OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
VIS_DS_ENDERECO VARCHAR(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL
```

Mas só funciona assim:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO 
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS_OBSERVACAO VARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.SIX_POSTO 
ALTER COLUMN VIS_DS_ENDERECO VARCHAR(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
NULL
```

Para cada `ALTER TABLE` só pode existir um `ALTER COLUMN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer mais de um comando para adicionar `ADD` ou remover `DROP COLUMN`, mas não pode para o `ALTER COLUMN`. O comando `ALTER TABLE` não permite que você faça mais de um `ALTER COLUMN`, ou seja, você precisará fazer um `ALTER TABLE` para cada alteração de coluna que tiver que ser feita.